# How to set state via a method from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

Using Flutter and trying to move out a Widget to another class to keep it modular.
Problem is one of the inner Widget has a setState in it. But when I move it out to another class, it is not valid as it is not stateful. Initially thought of passing in a Function and replace that with the setState function itself but that doesn't seem to work. How can I come around this?

Current method that works fine. I plan to move out everything from line 6 (child: Center) to another class as this is going to be repeated via a PageView. Going to be swiping this page to next page, each looking the same, only the text changes.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Did you hear about the claustrophobic astronaut?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "He just needed a little space.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Icon(heartStatus),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (heartStatus == FontAwesomeIcons.heart) {
                            heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart;
                          } else {
                            heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.heart;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shareAlt),
                      onTap: (){
                        print('shared');
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is after moving it to anther class which won't work as set state is not valid here. Passing in function here throws error -> Unnecessary statement

```
Widget getPageData(Function function){
  IconData heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.heart;

  return Center(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Did you hear about the claustrophobic astronaut?",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "He just needed a little space.",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(heartStatus),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    //tried passing in function here
                    if (heartStatus == FontAwesomeIcons.heart) {
                      heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart;
                    } else {
                      heartStatus = FontAwesomeIcons.heart;
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shareAlt),
                onTap: (){
                  print('shared');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `InheritedWidget`, `Scoped Model`, `BLoC Pattern` or a callback function. I'm not yet familiar enough with these to give a complete answer, but I hope this will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your `function`:

```
Widget getPageData(Function function){...}
```

To a `Customised Widget`

```
class CustomizeWidget extend StatefulWidget{

}
class _CustomizeWidgetState extend State<StatefulWidget>{
   /// in the build function, you can call setState
}
```